# How to avoid side effect?

Tags: java, side-effects

To avoid side effect: 
I don't want to change the pramaeter object attribute values, in my method. I prefer to create a new one that will represent the result and return it.

Avoiding side effect is only really important in multithread environment, but still good practice to have. f(X)=Y ,is good to be able to compare both objects, the one u received as argument and the one u giving as result.

That means, I need to map all the attribute in my IN paramater object to my OUT new instance object created. This will make some code like:

```
groundCertResult.setExpirationDate(pGroundCertificate.getExpirationDate());
groundCertResult.setValidationDate(pGroundCertificate.getValidationDate());
groundCertResult.setId(pGroundCertificate.getId());
```

**that it can make a lot of lines in my method :$**

I can also do without mapping that much values, just adding a line

```
//use findByID without mapping that much 
final GroundCertificate groundCertResult =
    groundCertificateDao.findById(pGroundCertificate.getId());
```

**but this will end up in an access to DB, and more processing.**

Do some generic method using reflection, to map an object to an other? That will be costy, in performance.

What will u choose? Depnding on the project needs. Taking into consideration maintainability, sacalability...

Answer (score 1):

1. You may want to have a look at [Cloneable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and `Object.clone()`. If a shallow copy of your object is sufficient you don't need to write any additional code. `Object.clone()` will do that for you.
2. Make sure you really want/need this approach. If you are not sure what/if side effects might occur otherwise, review your code to find out.
3. Be consistent. Don't mix copying and modifying operations in your implementation.
4. Think about what needs to be done if, in the future, you or someone wants to use a descendant of your `GroundCertificate`.

Comment: I think a copy constructor would be better in this case than implementing `clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only good in a multi-threaded environment, although the risk of side-effects causing *problems* are greatly reduced.

Side-effects increase the difficulty of reasoning about what code actually does. You need to identify all the places state can be changed, and there's no way to do that without slogging through everything and identifying those places. "Spooky action at a distance."

There are several libraries that do various types of bean property copies, like Apache's [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). Whether not not it's worth it from an efficiency standpoint depends on the situation.

While it's not a "pure" approach, I'm also not violently opposed to returning a modified parameter object, as long as it's clear that the original object is being modified. More often than not, I'm setting the parameter object back to that value anyway. When I'm not, I try to make the code indicate either by chaining in some sort of copy functionality.

Ultimately, for me, it's all about clarity, and I'll take clarity over purity when I can when I'm forced to do so, and it's safe.